# spring-aop "None or multiple beans found in Spring context for type class"

Tags: spring, spring-boot, aop, aspect

I am not able to apply an aspect to my spring rest endpoint components for logging purposes.
All of endpoint classes are implemented like

```
@Component
@Path("mypath")
public class MyEndpointImpl extends MyEndpoint
{...}
```

Without aspect everything works fine without any errors. When I try to apply aspect I just get list of errors for each endpoint class like "None or multiple beans found in Spring context for type class **.*EndpointImpl" and no aspect is intercepting endpoints' methods. However everything works fine as if there were no error message and no aspect.

Interesting is when I create e.g. simple filter

```
@Component
@WebFilter(filterName = "MySimpleFilter", urlPatterns = "/*")
public class SimpleFilter implements javax.servlet.Filter
{...}
```

in package of pointcut, doFilter method of SimpleFilter is intercepted by the aspect as would expect for all endpoint methods.

What could be a problem here, any ideas?

Comment: Aspect wraps each object in a proxy so it looks like spring cannot find the proxied MyEndpointImpl instances. Guess it depends on how you configure aspect as well as beans detecting (package scan etc.). Need more info

Comment: Thank you for your reply @StanislavL . Anyway I am curious, why is this not an problem for SimpleFilter mentioned?

Comment: it looks like it is only in case implementation and API of rest-endpoints are separated. Really weird spring...

Answer (score -1):

In my environment the Problem disappeared when adding the following to the application.yml file

spring.aop.proxy-target-class: true

Comment: This should be a comment. Until you gain enough reputation to post comments, please refrain from answering questions in such a way or do some more research and post more elaborate answers.